# Is this bug when copy snippet to answer ( code is copied in the answer )

Tags: bug, edits, design

Is this bug copy snippet to answer or design issue?

When i click copy snippet to answer in the available button of answer? snippet is copied correctly to the answer but when i click on Javaccript/HTML/CSS snippet or Cntrl+M.

I see when code snippet edit empty but copied code is available in the answer.

Comment: When you click the "Snippet" button in the toolbar, you're *always* creating a new snippet. Regardless of whether you've copied anything or otherwise. To edit a snippet already in the answer, click the "edit this snippet" in the post preview. Does that explain it…?